# Running netbeans project with administrator rights on windows windows

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, exec, administrator

I want to run my NetBeans project as an administrator on windows 8.1, in order to access windows commands that are available only in administrator mode : 
for example :

```
 try {
        CommandLine commandLine=new CommandLine("cmd.exe");
        commandLine.addArgument("/c");
        commandLine.addArgument("ipconfig");
        DefaultExecutor defaultExecutor=new DefaultExecutor();
        defaultExecutor.getStreamHandler().setProcessOutputStream(System.in);
        defaultExecutor.execute(commandLine);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

throw an `ExecuteException`
Note that it works well if, for example, I replace `"ipconfig"` with `"dir"` which is a non-administrative command

I tried to run NetBeans as an administrator, but apparently, it has no effect on running the project as an administrator

Regards

Comment: Have you tried using `runas` in your `ComandLine`?

Comment: thank for answering, what i am intending to do is to run all the project with full admin rights, which will make the processes created by de application with full admin rights too, it is purely for testing purpose.